# PythonAnywhere ImportError: No module named wsgi

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I was deploying django app to PythonAnywhere.
Environment I am using is:
Python 2.7
Django 1.8

In _pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py, I have:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

When I run it, it is giving error as:

> ImportError: No module named wsgi

What is the solution for it?

Comment: Are you sure you installed the right version of Django into your virtualenv?

Comment: I have installed django 1.8 and above two lines should work for it

Comment: Then maybe something went wrong with the install. Try deleting your virtualenv, re-creating it and re-installing.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `pythonpath` to where `wsgi.py` is located